# What does the following syntax with the combination of erase and remove mean?

Tags: c++, containers, erase

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between erase and remove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799314/difference-between-erase-and-remove)

suppose i have a container.... what does  the following mean.

```
c.erase(remove(c.begin(),c.end(),99),c.end());
```

aren't erase and remove the same? What is the specific function of  erase and remove in the above example?

Comment: Look up the erase remove-idiom. I know it's on here somewhere. Basically, algorithms have no knowledge of the container they're working on, so actually erasing them is impossible.

Comment: I can't believe it's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It removes all elements equal to `99` from container `c`.

[`std::remove`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/remove) doesn't actually remove any elements. It moves all the elements of interest to the second part of the container, and returns an iterator indicating the first of these. Then the `erase` member function takes an iterator range to actually remove the elements from the container.

See [erase-remove idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom).

Comment: can we write the code something like this? c.erase(c.begin(),c.end(),99);

Comment: @Saikiran No, but in general, you have to look at the interface of each container. You can certainly not do it with `std::vector`, `std::deque` and `std::list`. These all require either one iterator, or two, specifying a range of elements to be deleted.

Comment: @juanchopanza In fact you *can* do it with `std::list`, just not with `erase`, but `list.remove(99)`, which might be a better choice over *erase-remove*'s optimization for block erasure that doesn't buy you anything for a list.