# Difference between two features of vector

Tags: c++, vector

What would be the difference between:

```
std::vector::erase
```

and

```
std::vector::clear
```

What I want to do is to get rid of all elements, positions, including memory addresses and having no exception thrown.

```
vector<array<double,1000>> S1(1000);
```

I would like at the end to get rid of the 1000*2 created memory addresses.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between erase and remove](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799314/difference-between-erase-and-remove)

Comment: Perhaps have a look at [a good reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). It sounds like you want to call ``clear()``.

Comment: @Vijay ``remove`` != ``clear``.

Comment: @Vijay no sorry, I was well clear, about the different between ERASE and CLEAR, and not ERASE and REMOVE.

Comment: @juanchopanza  The allocated memory will not be released with Clear apparently. But I do want to release the memory.

Comment: @MelMed Good point. Then you need to perform the ``swap`` trick: ``std::vector<T>().swap(myOldVector);``

Comment: @MelMed What allocated memory, that of the `vector`? `erase` won't do that either, you have to use the swap-trick for that (or in C++11 `std::vector::shrink_to_fit`, but even that is not guaranteed to work). Though, *"get rid of all elements, positions, including memory addresses"* sounds a bit weird and I hope you're not after deleting dynamically allocated objects stored in the vector.

Comment: @ChristianRau He gives `std::vector<std::array<double, 1000>>` as the type, so there shouldn't be any pointers.  (His last sentence sounds weird to me, too.)

Comment: *"I would like at the end to get rid of the 1000*2 created pointers."* - There are no 1000*2 pointers in a `vector<array<double,1000>>(1000)`, where did you get this idea from? There are just 1000 `std::array<double,1000>`s in it, nothing else (and those won't contain any pointers either).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only sure way to release the memory that I can think of is to swap with a temporary vector:

```
vector<array<double,1000>> S1(1000);
...
vector<array<double,1000>>().swap(S1);
```

Although this might look strange at first, it is a known, widely used idiom.

In C++11, moving from the original vector might be an option, although it is not guaranteed to clear the memory or even clear the vector (I cannot think of a reason why an implementation wouldn't do that though):

```
{
  vector<array<double,1000>> tmp(std::move(S1));
} // tmp dies on exiting scope, memory is cleared
```

Altenratively, a call to `std::vector::shrink_to_fit` could result in memory de-allocation, but there are no guarantees:

```
S1.clear();
S1.shrink_to_fit();
```

Comment: In C++11, `std::vector` has a `shrink_to_fit` member, which _should_ be the best solution.  (The standard doesn't guarantee much in this regard, but QoI should mean that it works.)

Comment: And the solution with `move` looks more like obfuscation than anything else to me.

Comment: @JamesKanze *"The standard doesn't guarantee much in this regard"* - And that's the problem why it is a completely rubbish function. Of course an implementation would be stupid not to implement `shrink_to_fit` properly, but that's not what the standard guarantees. It's like saying *"here you have fixed width integer types, except when you haven't"*. Though I agree that the move-solution is counter-intuitive.

Comment: @JamesKanze I added a line about ``shrink_to_fit``. I think the swap trick is the only guaranteed method, but it still does look like a bit of hack to me.

Comment: Though the answer got accepted, from his rather strangely worded question I have the strong feeling the OP didn't nearly understand what is going on and what he really needs to do.

Comment: @JamesKanze As for the move solution, I guess it is a matter of familiarity. We're probably used to the swap trick, and I would naturally opt for that solution, but I have seen it confuse the heck out of newcomers to C++.

Comment: +1. It may be worth mentioning that `clear()` has a `noexcept` guarantee (which is possible because the destructors of vector elements are required to be destructible without exceptions). `erase()` doesn't have that guarantee because in theory it could trigger moves/copies (of course it won't do that when you delete _all_ elements). `shrink_to_fit`, for some reason, isn't `noexcept` either.

Comment: "moving from" doesn't really work out well, since the vector is then only capable of being destroyed, not of being reused.

Comment: @PlasmaHH That is entirely wrong. The assumption that you can only destroy moved-from objects is a common misunderstanding. In general a moved-from object is in a *valid but unspecified state*, so you can do whatever you want with it that doesn't require preconditions, like e.g. `=`, `clear` or `empty` (otherwise the default `std::swap` wouldn't even work). See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7027523/743214). Though I'm not sure the standard guarantees the moved-from vector to be empty, but even then it wouldn't guarantee it to deallocate its storage.

Comment: @ChristianRau I don't think there is any guarantee the vector will be cleared, let alone its memory de-allocated.

Comment: @juanchopanza Maybe even the former but most definitely not the latter, which makes it useless for freeing, anyway. But the statement that you can only destroy it was rubbish nevertheless.

Comment: @ChristianRau I think that the intent is clear, and there are so many things the standard doesn't guarantee.  Am implementation can, for example, create a vector with a capacity of 1000 when the default constructor is invoked.  (In this case, I suspect that the weasel wording in the standard is for cases where memory allocation has very strict alignment requirements, and the implementation of vector ensures that capacity is always a multiple of these.)

Comment: @jogojapan The exception issue is well spotted.  And `shrink_to_fit` can't have a `noexcept` guarantee, since it may have to reallocate and copy elements.  (And I agree that there is nothing intuitive about the swap idiom.  It's just one of those recognized patterns.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Ah right. `shrink_to_fit` isn't `noexcept` because of the same reason why `erase` isn't. I should have seen that.. Anyway. All is clear now.

Comment: @jogojapan It's worse that `erase`, actually.  The only reason `erase` can throw is if the copy constructor or assignment operator of `T` throws (so it cannot throw on `std::vector<int>`).  `shrink_to_fit` also requires an allocation, which can also fail.

Answer (score 4):

`erase` gets rid of elements selectively by position. `clear` gets rid of all elements unconditionally, and can be considered syntactic sugar for a call to `v.erase(v.begin(),v.end());`

Comment: What about deleting the memory addresses, do I use erase?

Comment: deleting what memory addresses? You may need to show some code (or ask a more specific question)

Answer (score 0):

Erase lets you specify begin and end positions whereas clear clears the whole Vector.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/clear/

Answer (score 0):

The function `clear()` empties the vector. The function `erase()` removes selective elements (there are several [overloads](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase)). `erase(v.begin(), v.end());` is equivalent to calling `clear();`. The created memory will still be reserved for possible future use. If you want to be sure to free all this memory, then call `v.clear();` and then [`v.shrink_to_fit()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit), if you have a C++11 compiler. (There's no actual guarantee that the memory will be freed, it's just a request, but I don't know of any compiler which doesn't free the memory.) If you don't have C++11 compliance then use the alternative `std::vector<std::array<double,1000>>().swap(v);`. That's called the [shrink to fit idiom](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Shrink-to-fit).

Answer (score 0):

v.erase(v.begin(),v.end()) is equivalent to v.clear() where v is an object of any vector. Here clear will be used for delete all the vector elements but erase can we used to delete any specific element or range of element.