# std::list.remove is calling the destructor but doesn't delete it

Tags: c++, c++11

I am having a problem with std::list.

```
std::list<Component*> mComponents;
//add some pointer in it
Component * comp = getComponent("positionComponent");
mComponents.remove(comp);
```

For some reason, it calls the destructor of the comp pointer but doesn't delete it; items that are removed through destructor gets removed, while all the other items in the list kept intact. What can cause this behavior?

Comment: The destructor of a pointer does nothing...

Comment: Remove does not delete items from list:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799314/difference-between-erase-and-remove

Comment: not sure what you mean when you say it calls the destructor but doesn't delete it... does it call `Component::~Component()`, but doesn't free the memory? This code shouldn't be calling `Component::~Component()`, as it's not destroying a `Component`, just a `Component*`.

Comment: @VladimirM `std::list::remove` *does* remove an element; I think you're referring to `std::remove` the general iterator algorithm.

Comment: I think this was the weirdest thing I have seen in programming. I think XCode is having issues since I have been using it non stop all day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calling `list.remove` does call the destructor of the contained type, but in your case, the destructor for `Component *` is being called, which is a no-op. You must manually find the item and `delete` it before removing it.

```
auto item = std::find(mComponents.begin(), mComponents.end(), comp);
if(item != mComponents.end()) {
  delete *item;
  mComponents.remove(item);
}
```

This is the reason why it is not advisable to stick raw pointers in standard containers. You should use `std::list<std::unique_ptr<Component>>` instead. The `unique_ptr` will call `delete` on the managed object for you.

Or if you're using a pre-C++11 compiler, [`boost::ptr_list`](http://www.boost.org/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_list.html) is another option.

Comment: Even though the question I asked and didn't make sense at all (why would a pointer call destructor). I am guessing it was a memory leak that was giving unexpected behavior. I have been considering using smart pointers. I just needed to make the code work before I get into adding this amazing feature.

Comment: @Gasim: If you need to delete the item every time it is removed from the list, clearly the list *owns* the item. Why don't just `std::list<Component>`? Why storing pointers?

Comment: Do you mean `delete *item;`?