# Handling constness of pointed values in map keys

Tags: c++, types, casting, stl, constants

I have the following code:

```
#include <map>
using namespace std;
struct A {};

map</*const*/ A *, int> data;

int get_attached_value(const A *p) {
    return data.at(p);
}
void reset_all() {
    for (const auto &p : data) *p.first = A();
}
```

My problem is that this code fails on a type error both when I comment and uncomment the `const` in the type of `data`. Is there any way I can solve this without using `const_cast` and without losing the `const` in `get_attached_value`?

Comment: You CANNOT (important!) change std::map/std::set keys. NEVER. It WILL break std::map/std::set's internal data structures and may lead to tremendous memory leaks/segfaults/memory corruption/etc. NEVER do that. NEVER.

Comment: Yes, you could make `get_attached_value` take an `A *`.

Comment: @nabijaczleweli Notice that the OP is *not* changing the keys. The key is a pointer. They're just changing the object pointed to by that pointer.

Comment: I am not changing the map keys, I am changing the value pointed by it, please read carefully.

Comment: @Angew - I thought about it but it lies to the caller as if the function may modify an `A`, which it never does.

Comment: @Angew I see your (valid) point, but depending on the implementation and/or on the additional template arguments this *might* break.

Comment: @nabijaczleweli - Can you give such an example?

Comment: @tohava `struct Aless {
  constexpr bool operator()(const A * lhs, const A * rhs) const {
    return *lhs < *rhs;
  }
}` and `map<A *, int, Aless>`. Or specialize `std::less<A *>`. Unlikely, but possible.

Comment: @nabijaczleweli - ok, but this means that in general it is dangerous to do any kind of mutation based on key (if the key is an int, it can still be used as an index to an array for example)

Comment: This looks like you need heterogeneous lookup. That's supported in C++14, if you change the comparator of `map` from `less<A*>` to `less<>`, à la `map<A*, int, less<>>`, and use `find` instead of `at`. [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9b5801631f2ba868)

Comment: @tohava Correct - you can use it as long as you don't break the constness of the key, but you can use it without modifying it (as in your example, indexing array, etc).

Comment: @dyp - Thanks, if you put it as an answer I'll give you a +1 and a correct

Comment: @tohava Does your compiler and standard library implementation actually support that C++14 feature? (Note I've added a live example so you can test it.)

Comment: @dyp - I can't use C++14 for this project, but your answer is the most correct one.

Comment: @dyp - After reading a bit about what the feature you described actually means.

Comment: Well it's not a helpful answer if it doesn't fulfil the requirements of solutions to *your* problem. Certainly, it should *not* be the accepted answer, anyway.

Comment: @tohava - Isn't the problem that your key type and `get_attached_value`'s type should be the same? The type you're using as a key is a pointer to a _non-const instance of A_, while the  `get_attached_value` uses a pointer to a _const instance of A_, so you cannot assign second to the first without breaking the constness of the pointee. Leaving const in both seems to compile (but `reset_all` breaks, obviously), and leaving const out works as well (gcc 4.8.1). Also, using `A* const` in both places works (a const pointer to a non-const instance of A), and keeps the `reset_all` working.

Comment: IMHO, you should go with the `const_cast` solution in `get_attached_value`. **You** as the implementer of that function know that the pointee won't get modified, hence it's safe to use the `const_cast` there.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be in the **pointee type**, which has to be the same in both pointer declarations (map key type and the `get_attached_value`'s argument).

OP's code uses `const A*`, which is a pointer to a *const instance of class A* (an alternative spelling is `A const *`). Leaving this const in both map declaration and in `get_attached_value`' argument almost works, but `reset_all` does not allow you to assign a new value to `*p.first`, because the resulting type is `A const&` (which cannot be assigned into).

Removing both consts works as well, but OP wants to keep a const in `get_attached_value`.

One solution for OP's requirements, keeping as many consts as possible, seems to be to change the pointer type to a *const pointer to a non-const instance of A*. This will keep `reset_all` working, while allowing to use a const pointer in both map declaration and `get_attached_value`'s argument:

```
#include <map>
using namespace std;
struct A {};

map<A * const, int> data;

int get_attached_value(A * const p) {
    return data.at(p);
}
void reset_all() {
    for (const auto &p : data)
        *p.first = A();
}
```

Another possible solution, with map's key as non-const but the `get_attached_value`'s parameter const, could use `std::lower_bound` with a custom comparator to replace the `data.at()` call:

```
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
struct A {};

map<A*, int> data;

int get_attached_value(A const * const p) {
    auto it = std::lower_bound(data.begin(), data.end(), p,
        [] (const std::pair<A* const, int>& a, A const* const b) {
            return a.first < b;
        }
    );
    return it->second;
}
void reset_all() {
    for (const auto &p : data)
        *p.first = A();
}
```

However, this solution will be significantly less efficient than one that would use `map`'s native search functions - `std::lower_bound` [uses linear search when input iterators are not random access](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lower_bound/#complexity).

To conclude, the most efficient solution in C++11 or lower would probably use a const pointer as the map's key, and a `const_cast` in the `reset_all` function.

A bit more reading about const notation and pointers can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-and-int-const).

Comment: @tohava But then the `reset_all` method cannot work, because you are trying to assign a new value to the pointee (a const reference in that case).

Comment: In an ideal world, the map would be a map with a key who is a non-const pointer, and there would be an `at` method which works for const pointers as well (since it only gives access to the value, and avoids exposing the non-const pointer back to the caller)

Comment: @tohava What about using `std::lower_bound` to replace `at`? Would that be a solution satisfying your requirements? However, I'd argue that your question is a bit unclear and inconsistent with your previous comment, because uncommenting the const in your code would always break the `reset_all` method.

Comment: Wouldn't lower_bound require me to use `const_cast`?

Comment: Nope, the code I've written in the second example above compiles in gcc 4.8.1 .

Comment: `std::lower_bound` typically won't be efficient on `std::map`. The map has a special implementation as a member function: `std::map::lower_bound`.

Comment: @martin_pr - Did you try on your code or on the code where the const is on pointee and not pointer

Comment: @tohava - If you mean for `p` parameter, then yes, the code above works for all const combinations around `p`.

Comment: @martin_pr  - ok, I get it now. Btw, dyp mentioned heterogenous C++14 containers, which I think may be a way to combine your solution with the efficency of `map`

Comment: @dyp - `std::map` does have its own implementation of `lower_bound`, but it won't allow you to pass a custom comparator, which means that what OP is trying to achieve is not possible. About efficiency, you are probably right, but I'd argue that the difference won't be huge.

Comment: @tohava - Probably, but you said you can't use C++14 :)

Comment: The difference is that `std::lower_bound` will probably perform a **linear search** since it probably won't use the tree structure of the `std::map`. And a linear search in a tree is slow. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/20934717/

Comment: @dyp - Yes, you're right - for non-random access iterators, it will go linearly. Shame... I am not sure if there is a better solution without a const_cast in C++11 (or lower), though. I'll stick a warning in my answer.